# how to put numbering for Images in Listview

Tags: vb.net

How to add numbering Images in Listview and below attached the code.

```
Private Sub retrieve()
    ListView1.Clear()
    Dim imglist As New ImageList
    imglist.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
    ListView1.LargeImageList = imglist
    ListView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 200)
    Dim strsql As String = "select * from picEmploy where NumFile=" & TextBox1.Text
    Dim dt_images As New DataTable
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = strsql
    adp.SelectCommand = cmd
    adp.Fill(ds)
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim imb_buffer = CType(dr("pic"), Byte())
        Dim img_stream As New IO.MemoryStream(imb_buffer, True)
        img_stream.Write(imb_buffer, 0, imb_buffer.Length)
        imglist.Images.Add(dr("NumFile").ToString(), New Bitmap(img_stream))
        img_stream.Close()
        Dim lsvparent As New ListViewItem
        'lsvparent.Text = dr("pic").ToString
        lsvparent.ImageKey = dr("NumFile").ToString
        ListView1.Items.Add(lsvparent)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `lsvparent.Text = imagelist.Images.Count.ToString()`

Comment: ok its work thank you